# How To Get a Value From Dynamic TextBox?

Tags: c#

I have code like this.

==============================================================

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int cLeft = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewTextBox();
        TextBox1.Text=cLeft.Text<<how can i get this cleft value??
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
        txt.Left = 100;
        txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        return txt;
    }
}
}
```

How Can I get a value from this textbox?

I will write it on other textboxt.

Comment: do you mean the string written in the textbox?

Comment: What do you want actually ?

Comment: @chouaib yes, i want strng written in textbox,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cLeft` is not the textBox, it's an integer you are using for positioning the `TextBox`, for example via `txt.Top = cLeft * 25;`. Oddly, you are also using the value of `cLeft` in setting the `Text` value of the`TextBox`, but that's not really relevant to retrieving the text.

Instead, to retrieve the text, change your click handler to something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1=AddNewTextBox();
    //text is now available via
    textBox1.Text;
}
```